# Why is my setuptools not working in Python 3.9?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am having an issue with setuptools. I am trying to install [PyUSB](https://pyusb.github.io/pyusb/) for an Adafruit FT232H and apparently it needs a different fork than the standard PyUSB. I have that downloaded and I'm in the folder that has its *setup.py* files. When I run `python setup.py install` I get this:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "setup.py", line 18, in <module> from setuptools import setup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'`

I did some searching and I found hundreds of people saying to uninstall setuptools and reinstall it.  I have done that successfully but I still get the module not found error. It's at version 50.3.0.

I completely uninstalled Python and reinstalled everything with the same issue. How can I fix this?

Python 3

Comment: How are you installing setuptools?  Are you using pip?  If so, show us the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`.

Answer (score 2):

You need reinstall:

For Mac OS / Linux

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

For Windows

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: It seems to me while it is better to use 3.7 or 3.8 versions for stability.
But this my opinion))

Comment: Or may reinstall python

Comment: I have done pip uninstall setuptools and pip install setuptools about 100 times now.  I have uninstalled python completely and reinstalled.  None of that seems to work.

Comment: It seems 3.9 not stable this time )))

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Python 3.9 and installed 3.8 and that seems to have fixed this issue.